# Excel VBA add right-click button to addin

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to make an Addin with Pivot right-click button.
All the macros are working in the addin perfectly on every workbook that I open.

The problem is that the right-click buttons don't appear in other workbooks - only in the one with the addin.

Screenshot
[image]

As you can see I have written the code in ThisWorkbook module, and the Subs are Private. - I guess that somewhere here is the problem.

Would be very grateful if somebody can help.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found the problem.

Obviously, the first part of the code was preventing the buttons to appear in other workbooks.

Other than that, Temporary:=True. it should be False.